# How can I plot the training loss as a function of γ

Tags: python, scikit-learn

[ I am a statistics guy but I am not very good in coding. This could be a simple for loop and plotting issue]

How can I plot  the graph with estimators (or 1 to 150) as x-axis and training loss as y-axis, for different γ (learning rate= 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 1). I like to plot the line chart for different γ on one plot. It will be easier to do compare.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs
from sklearn.metrics import zero_one_loss
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor

X_train, y_train = make_blobs(n_samples=1000, n_features=10, centers=3,
random_state=10, cluster_std=5)


breg = GradientBoostingRegressor(learning_rate=0.1,
n_estimators=150, random_state=100)
breg.fit(X_train,y_train)
```

For γ or learning_rate=0.1, I can check the breg.train_score_ as:

array([0.57468338, 0.49988198, 0.43293686, 0.38219534, 0.33580473,
0.29832827, 0.26675631, 0.24067659, 0.21842987, 0.19817057,
0.18040607, 0.16585845, 0.15375498, 0.14213091, 0.1326827 ,
0.12492904, 0.11802082, 0.11265069, 0.10724528, 0.10237506,
0.09825622, 0.0948534 , 0.09180083, 0.08919955, 0.08660985,
0.08427062, 0.08218433, 0.08010646, 0.07845166, 0.07646058,
0.07511399, 0.07348535, 0.07191978, 0.07057382, 0.0694041 ,
0.06827032, 0.06751911, 0.06636306, 0.06553243, 0.06453646,
0.06382421, 0.06310264, 0.06255564, 0.06169868, 0.06106456,
0.06020758, 0.05956437, 0.0589683 , 0.05857613, 0.05835434,
0.05788804, 0.05734811, 0.05695127, 0.05617195, 0.05577267,
0.05535058, 0.05438471, 0.05415762, 0.05395474, 0.05359835,
0.05338581, 0.05261187, 0.05212596, 0.05177005, 0.05148665,
0.05125861, 0.05067917, 0.05050313, 0.04994986, 0.04934108,
0.04886436, 0.04844108, 0.04796545, 0.04787594, 0.04736417,
0.0469984 , 0.0463386 , 0.04610686, 0.04586156, 0.04555303,
0.04522064, 0.04500386, 0.04447497, 0.04422516, 0.04414786,
0.04367328, 0.04340406, 0.04290195, 0.04273739, 0.04259202,
0.04241596, 0.04182698, 0.04145753, 0.0410822 , 0.04101794,
0.04061812, 0.04032768, 0.04006762, 0.03997287, 0.03981082,
0.03954574, 0.03949362, 0.03925316, 0.03879255, 0.03865009,
0.03833753, 0.03799245, 0.0377798 , 0.03766262, 0.03746877,
0.03684285, 0.03676621, 0.03646639, 0.0361836 , 0.03606436,
0.03594994, 0.03590734, 0.03543761, 0.03537628, 0.03513024,
0.03492127, 0.03465343, 0.03448113, 0.03434481, 0.03430889,
0.03394142, 0.03390877, 0.03385245, 0.03361713, 0.03348751,
0.0333572 , 0.0331197 , 0.03288531, 0.03259427, 0.03234941,
0.03214568, 0.03187251, 0.03154897, 0.03129557, 0.03078963,
0.03065767, 0.03024594, 0.0300378 , 0.02959993, 0.02947694,
0.02914165, 0.02910925, 0.02903385, 0.028969  , 0.02879665])

Now, How can I get a plot for all γ (learning rate= 0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 1) with B=150 in X axis and traininng loss in Y axis. Something like

[image]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Pick a plotting library of your choice and go through its tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't see a point of doing this, because you know how the graph will look like. With the same number of trees, the higher the learning rate, the steeper the decrease in TRAINING LOSS. Theoretically, you can have the TRAINING LOSS and low as you want by setting high learning rates and large number of trees. I think it is more important to have a validation dataset and monitor the TRAINING LOSS AND THE VALIDATION LOSS together to prevent over-fitting when you see the validation loss go up while training loss keeps decreasing.

Comment: Hi Kavin, I just need to make a comparison with different learning rate to see any relation between round and learning rate.thanks